# Chrome stretches website images, Edge, IE, Firefox not

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-chrome

I find it hard to figure out why the images on the home page of  https://www.kerkradio.za/index.php show up stretched. I am no boffin at CSS or so, but in IE, FF, and Edge they are all showing the images fine. I found one reference to a solution here ([Chrome is stretching my images vertically, however everything works fine in Firefox/Edge](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53839179/chrome-is-stretching-my-images-vertically-however-everything-works-fine-in-fire)), but it did not help really.

I have had a look at instances where the image height and width are set to auto and changed it to 100% instead. No luck. I am sure I am missing something in the css-es.

Please refer to the code of https://www.kerkradio.co.za/index.php. Scroll down to where all the church image cards are displayed.

I have been at it for more than 3 hours now.

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.

Answer (score 1):

I guess you need remove height from this selectors:

```
.card-img img
```

Look like some different behavior flexbox and image calculation size. So img contains:

```
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
```

chrome expands image to 100% original height, while firefox image resize to 100% container height

Comment: Its located in https://www.kerkradio.co.za/assets/theme/css/style.css but does not have a height attribute.

Comment: @SytzeVisser its located in https://www.kerkradio.co.za/assets/mobirise/css/mbr-additional.css at 1845

Comment: Tim, You make it sound/look so easy. I have some studying to do to see how it hangs together. Many thanks - I will upvote your answer as soon as I have enough reputation points.